# Can an instance that is a property of an instance access the other properties of the main instance?

Tags: php, class, oop

Suppose I have the following (PHP for reference)

```
myClassA{
    private $myClassB;
    private $myClassC;

    function __construct(){
        $this->myClassB = new myClassB();
        $this->myClassC = new myClassC();
    }
}
```

And let's say that `myClassB` is a database connection manager that will establish and close connections, but never write or read from the connections.

I now want to write with `myClassC` to a database connection being managed through `myClassB`. Let's say that `myClassC` has a function called `save_user()` that saves user data.

Is it possible for `save_user` to contain code which references the instance of `myClassB` which is inside `myClassA`. For example if I know that `myClassC` will only ever be created inside a `myClassA` and a `myClassA` will always have a `myClassB` to manage its connections, then is it possible for `myClassC` to contain a line of code such as

```
//$this refers to myClassC 
$connection_to_write_to = $this->OBJECT_IM_INSIDE_OF->myClassB->db_connection_1->;
```

I guess I'm wondering if functions inside `myClassC` would be able to access the properties of `myClassA` directly or must I do

```
myClassC->myFunction(myClassA->property_I_want)
```

to access the properties of `myClassA` that I want to use in `myClassC`.

Comment: No, there are no automatic back-references. If you want this, you need to add a property to `ClassC` that holds this, and pass `this->myClassB` as an argument to the `ClassC` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ClassC` definition, you should do:

```
class ClassC {
    private parentClassB;

    function __construct($classB) {
        $this->parentClassB = $classB;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then your `ClassA` constructor would look like:

```
function __construct(){
    $this->myClassB = new myClassB();
    $this->myClassC = new myClassC($this->myClassB);
}
```